# Your browser doesn‘t support pasting with the toolbar button or context menu option

Tags: html, bootstrap-4, ckeditor, textarea, rich-text-editor

Hello everyone how are you? I'm going to add the text editor bar by using the code the **CKEDITOR** every thing is run good but problem is that when I click on the editor **copy and past** button then its give me error like

> Press Ctrl+V to paste. Your browser doesn‘t support pasting with the toolbar button or context menu option.
>
> Press Ctrl+Shift+V to paste. Your browser doesn‘t support pasting with the toolbar button or context menu option.
>
> Press Ctrl+V to paste. Your browser doesn‘t support pasting with the toolbar button or context menu option.

Can anyone please tell me what's I can do to solve this error its start work when I click on the text editor button and at the last the error I would like to show you in pic so the bellow pic is the error maybe you can understand easily when seeing the error pic

[image: Error picture of my problem]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Editor Example</title>
    <script src="https://cdn.ckeditor.com/4.10.1/standard/ckeditor.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <textarea name="text_editor"></textarea>
    <script>
        CKEDITOR.replace( 'text_editor' );
    </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this code

```
CKEDITOR.on("instanceReady", function(event) {
    event.editor.on("beforeCommandExec", function(event) {
        // Show the paste dialog for the paste buttons and right-click paste
        if (event.data.name == "paste") {
            event.editor._.forcePasteDialog = true;
        }
        // Don't show the paste dialog for Ctrl+Shift+V
        if (event.data.name == "pastetext" && event.data.commandData.from == "keystrokeHandler") {
            event.cancel();
        }
    })
});
```

Comment: ok thanks its start working when i add this code in script tag its do start working sir can you please give my post positive vote so that's my reputation increase

Comment: This answer needs more explanation.  Why is this necessary?  Is there a bug in CKEditor?

Comment: Working for me. CKeditor version 4.17

Comment: Source for this solution, and context (read from the top of this link): https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor4/issues/469#issuecomment-524185244

Comment: How to to that in react?